# When using 'ImageDataGenerator' in Keras and passing this directly when training my model, are the images modified to augment the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So I am building an image classifier, and using Keras' ImageDataGenerator class with the following parameters:

```
ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255, rotation_range=40, width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, 
horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest'
)
```

I then use this instance of the generator for my training data with the following code:

```
train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=binary_df, directory='../train', x_col='Image', y_col='Label',
target_size=(target_size[0],target_size[1]),
batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical',interpolation='nearest'
)
```

And then finally, this generator is passed directly to the 'fit_generator' function in Keras to train my model as follows:

```
binary_model.fit_generator(
binary_train_generator, epochs=100, shuffle=True)
```

My question is, does the generator automatically augment the data as specified when creating the generator (horizontal flipping, rotation, etc.) and pass this when training the model, or do I need to use the generator to create the new data first, and then pass that onto my 'fit_generator' function?

Thank you!

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for fixing up the code formatting for me!

Comment: No worries, just make sure you know how to do it yourself next time

Comment: @desertnaut Yup, will do, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ImageDataGenerator documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) and especially function **flow_from_dataframe** you are using.

Citing docs:

> Takes the path to a directory & generates batches of augmented data.

So it will generate augmented data for the model for you.

**BTW:** Data is not augmented when creating the generator, it is augmented on a batch-to-batch basis when the model is fed.

**EDIT:** Number of images (training data points) stays the same, citing documentation:

> horizontal_flip: Boolean. Randomly flip inputs horizontally.

Some of your inputs are flipped at random, it's not like two separate images are fed (one flipped and the other one in the original, not augmented, version).

Comment: That's what I thought, but the reason I am asking is that for each epoch, there is always the same amount of images as in the original dataset that are getting processed (which I know because since steps = num_images // batch_size). And this makes me question whether there are actually any new images. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @taras.i08 Updated my answer

Comment: I see, so basically on each epoch the same number of images are being fed to the model, but on each batch they are random transformations of the original images based on the set parameters, right? Thanks again, much appreciated!